# Using React to change content on already present page using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I've just started learning React and was trying to create a chrome extension using it. I am trying to create an extension with a button whose onClick will highlight certain given words on a webpage. I am able to highlight words in content I am introducing to the page but not in the content already present on the page

Here is the code I have come up with -

There is a button on the popup HTML with class `highlight-hazardous-words`

popup.js (extensions popup):

```
window.onload = () => {
const $highlightHazardousButton = document.querySelector('.highlight-hazardous-words');

$highlightHazardousButton.onclick = () => {
    // Get active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true,
    }, (tabs) => {
        // Send message to script file
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        { injectApp: true },
        response => window.close()
);
});
};
};
```

main.js(main react app content lies here):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words"

class HighlightHazardous extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {searchWords : this.props.searchWords, textToHighlight : this.props.textToHighlight}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Highlighter
                highlightClassName="highlighted-text"
                searchWords = {this.state.searchWords}
                autoEscape = {true}
                textToHighlight = {document.body.innerText}
            />
        )
    }
}
// Message Listener function
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
    // If message is injectApp
    if(request.injectApp) {
        // Inject our app to DOM and send response
        injectApp();
        response({
            startedExtension: true,
        });
    }
});

function injectApp() {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "chromeExtensionReactApp");
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    ReactDOM.render(<HighlightHazardous searchWords={['hazardous', 'alcoholic']}/>, newDiv);
}
```

Here the newDiv appended has highlighted words with the whole page's body, I want to highlight hazardous or alcoholic present anywhere on any webpage and not in new div, basically, I don't want to inject this new div and change the content of the page already present.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to access web-page's DOM content is to use `Content Scripts` component where **Chrome Extensions** use content-scripts to mention a JS and CSS file in `manifest.json`, that need to be injected into the underlying page.

As stated below:

> The problem with our `create-react-app` is that the build step will
>   generate the output JS file in different name each time (if the
>   content changed). So we have no way to know the actual file name of
>   the JS file, hence we can’t mention it in our manifest.json file.

The workaround for this is to eject out of `create-react-app` and modify the webpack configuration by hand to create a separate entry point for content script.

Sources:

- [Injecting React app to page as content script](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39)
- [Chrome extension mutating running react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825895/chrome-extension-mutating-running-react-application) (Related SO post)

Comment: Another option is that you could inject an iframe into the DOM and load the react app's `index.html` into the frame.

Comment: And yet another option is that you could rewire your build to prevent code splitting (and give the output JS file a static name) as described here: https://mtm.dev/disable-code-splitting-create-react-app/

Comment: Is this answer still true?